# RPI 2b wifi doesn't work

Tags: wifi

I get a RT5370 wireless adapter for my RPi 2b to connect the Internet.
I check that my adapter works good (I can use it scan the network and truly see the wifi that I want to use), and when I run sudo

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

It just says reconfiguring network interfaces...done. Nothing strange.
I'm confused why I still cannot connect to the Internet. I ran

```
ping google.com
```

and it said

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

For clarity, here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa_roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet static 
address xxxx
netmask xxxx
gateway xxxx
```

Here is my wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_conf=1

network = {
      ssid=
      password=
      xxxx
      xxxx
}
```

Does anyone have ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong wpa_supplicant.conf setting, It should be:

```
network={
    ssid="yourssid"
    psk="yourpassword"
}
```

Your /etc/network/interfaces should remain as default:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And if you want to assign a static IP, you do it in /etc/dhcpcd.conf, by adding the following lines to the end of the configuration file:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.xxx/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Replace the IP addresses with your own network/router IP addresses if it is different from the example.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method. But I don't have dhcpcd.conf in /etc/. So I don't use a static address to check. But still, when I try ping google.com, it says unknown host google.com. Ping 8.8.8.8 says the network is unreachable.

Comment: What OS and version you are using? Raspbian Jessie or something else?

Comment: Yeah, I use Raspbian.

Comment: That's strange, dhcpcd.conf should be there by default even on a fresh Raspbian Jessie installation. Without it, your DHCP and domain server won't function correctly. I would suggest you try to create a new SD card and test it out.